# Install the VS 2015 and Intel Fortran Compiler 2016 on Win10 but still not working

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran95

I just installed Windows 10. I have install two versions of Visual Studio installed (2015 and 2017) on my system and also install Intel Fortran Compiler 2016. Just run the simple code

```
 program Console3

 implicit none

 ! Variables

 ! Body of Console3
 print *, 'Hello World'

 end program Console3
```

it does work properly when run inside a VS 2015 command prompt and show the following error "rc.exe not found"

Comment: Does it work in the VS IDE?  Did you install 2017 after 2015?  VS goes bezerk if the different versions are not installed in chronological order.

Comment: @cup I install the both version of VS on my system.

Comment: possible duplicate of any of 2 dozen discussions on stackoverflow and software.intel.com.